# Woocommerce TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product

I have a problem with `add to cart` button on variable products. When I look at errors via Firebug I see the following error :

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function() {
Location : plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js?ver=2.1.12
```

[Screen from FIREBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH3Vv.jpg)

*Edited:* It is Wordpress site with Woocommerce plugin. I didn't do anything with this file or with jquery. 
[Page link](http://mizulife.sk)

JS file:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
    if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
        return false;

    // Ajax add to cart
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function() {

        // AJAX add to cart request
        var $thisbutton = $( this );

        if ( $thisbutton.is( '.product_type_simple' ) ) {

            if ( ! $thisbutton.attr( 'data-product_id' ) )
                return true;

            $thisbutton.removeClass( 'added' );
            $thisbutton.addClass( 'loading' );

            var data = {
                action: 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',
                product_id: $thisbutton.attr( 'data-product_id' ),
                quantity: $thisbutton.attr( 'data-quantity' )
            };

            // Trigger event
            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );

            // Ajax action
            $.post( wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {

                if ( ! response )
                    return;

                var this_page = window.location.toString();

                this_page = this_page.replace( 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' );

                if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                }

                // Redirect to cart option
                if ( wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes' ) {

                    window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
                    return;

                } else {

                    $thisbutton.removeClass( 'loading' );

                    fragments = response.fragments;
                    cart_hash = response.cart_hash;

                    // Block fragments class
                    if ( fragments ) {
                        $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                            $( key ).addClass( 'updating' );
                        });
                    }

                    // Block widgets and fragments
                    $( '.shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals' ).fadeTo( '400', '0.6' ).block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: 'transparent url(' + wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_loader_url + ') no-repeat center', backgroundSize: '16px 16px', opacity: 0.6 } } );

                    // Changes button classes
                    $thisbutton.addClass( 'added' );

                    // View cart text
                    if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $thisbutton.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).size() === 0 ) {
                        $thisbutton.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' + 
                            wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>' );
                    }

                    // Replace fragments
                    if ( fragments ) {
                        $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                            $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                        });
                    }

                    // Unblock
                    $( '.widget_shopping_cart, .updating' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                    // Cart page elements
                    $( '.shop_table.cart' ).load( this_page + ' .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *', function() {

                        $( 'div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)' ).addClass( 'buttons_added' ).append( '<input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus" />' ).prepend( '<input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />' );

                        $( '.shop_table.cart' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                        $( 'body' ).trigger( 'cart_page_refreshed' );
                    });

                    $( '.cart_totals' ).load( this_page + ' .cart_totals:eq(0) > *', function() {
                        $( '.cart_totals' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();
                    });

                    // Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas
                    $( 'body' ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ fragments, cart_hash ] );
                }
            });

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    });

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you add javascript files correctly in the sequence ??

Comment: Hi. It's wordpress site with Woocommerce e-commerce plugin... I didn't do anything with javascript files or jquery.

Comment: try disabling other plugins..

Comment: I didn't install nothing new it works well few days ago. I don't know what could happen.

Answer (score 0):

First check if any jquery file is missing and use `jQUERY` in place of `$`in your code and also use [noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) 
.This may help you get out of your problem.Which hook you are adding to add jquery in your site.

Comment: Hi I added the JS File to the first post So i need to add `$.noConflict();` to beginning of file ?

Comment: yes.and have you changed your `$` to `jQuery` and checked when your jquery file is loaded before or after jquery core file ?

Comment: replace all `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: Ok so I replace all `$(` with `JQuery(`  and now there is error :` TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function
 
return true;`

Comment: check when your jquery file is loaded and when your core jquery file is loaded .

Comment: JQuery core files are in footer : `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.9" type="text/javascript">` and no .js files befor this.

Comment: When I checked Net in Firebug there is first loaded Jquery.min.js and the file with error is after that... this js is used for add to cart process i think.

Comment: I checked your site and this line `jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function() {`  try to add this click on body or something else and after `document` `ready` , that may work .